# 400 : [no body] - Bad request while sending POST request to the server

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc, microservices

I have generated (openapi) payload object.

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({
  MyPayload.JSON_PROPERTY_MY_PROPERTY
})
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.JavaClientCodegen", date = ...")
public class MyPayload {
  public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_MY_PROPERTY = "my_properties";
  private Map<String, MyPropery> myProperties = null;
...
    }
```

When my client micro-service sending post request - it failed with

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 : [no body]
```

However if I would send pure Json as a payload from Postman - seems working fine, coming to the server.

As far as I understand issue on client side, can't find the reason (((

Below code of my client (spring-web 5.3.14)

```
private MyClient getMyClient() {
    MyClient myClient = new MyClient();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setHttpClient(HttpClients.custom().setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier()).build());

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    restTemplate.setInterceptors(
        Collections.singletonList(
            (ClientHttpRequestInterceptor) new TenantAwareClientInterceptor(storage)));
    ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(restTemplate);
    apiClient.setBasePath("https://myMS:poty/api/v1/...");
    myClient.setApiClient(apiClient);

    return myClient;
  }
```

May it be because of some differences between objects that are in my payload and objects that unmarshalled on server side?

**UPD:** Seems something wrong with the payload.
When I am creating payload with all fields null - everything is working fine...

What might be wrong with payload?

Comment: Can share the client code as well?

Comment: @Supritam, I updated the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to find the reason. This happens due to missing property in the base class of one of the members within my payload.

Here are the [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72396593/jackson-mapper-could-not-resolve-subtype-of-simple-type-class-missing-type)